# asyncio : How to queue object when an exception occurs

Tags: python, exception, queue, python-asyncio, telethon

Hi I have to process several objects queued 5 at time.
I have a queue of 5 items.
Sometimes process fails and an exception occurs:

```
async def worker(nam):
while True:
    queue_item = await queue.get()
```

Worker starts the process loop and tries to process items

```
try:
        loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
        task = loop.create_task(download(queue_item, path))
        download_result = await asyncio.wait_for(task, timeout=timeout)

        except asyncio.TimeoutError:
```

unfortunately the process timed out.
Can I add like this ?

```
     except asyncio.TimeoutError:
     await queue.put(queue_item)
```

I want to process again that item on next round
Thank

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can re-queue an object *at the end* of the queue for processing. A simple
example based on your code:

```
import asyncio
from random import randrange


async def download(item):
    print("Process item", item)

    if randrange(4) == 1:  # simulate occasional event
        await asyncio.sleep(100)  # trigger timeout error


async def worker(queue):
    while True:
        queue_item = await queue.get()
        try:
            result = await asyncio.wait_for(download(queue_item), timeout=1)
        except asyncio.TimeoutError:
            print("Timeout for ", queue_item)
            await queue.put(queue_item)
        queue.task_done()


async def main():
    q = asyncio.Queue()
    asyncio.create_task(worker(q))
    for i in range(5):  # put 5 items to process
        await q.put(i)
    await q.join()


asyncio.run(main())
```

```
Process item 0
Timeout for  0
Process item 1
Process item 2
Process item 3
Timeout for  3
Process item 4
Process item 0
Process item 3
```

Comment: Wonderful, Thanks Alex, have a nice day.